# Necessary condition for equal probability of rank?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, examples-counterexamples

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two continuous random variables. Is $\mathbb{E}[X] = \mathbb{E}[Y]$ a necessary condition for having $P(X>Y) = P(X<Y) = 1/2$? Can anyone provide a counter-example?

Comment: No.  Whether the means are equal is not sufficient to tell you that the medians are equal.

Comment: let's see - Y is 10 with probability 1, X is 0 with probability 1/2, it is 1000 with probability half, so one has E=10 and the other E=500.  however, the other condition is met

Comment: @Cato continuous random variables

Comment: it doesn't really matter, you could have a continuous probability with their probabilities centred around the values I gave, with zero or very low probabilites elsewhere

Comment: @Cato +1, that sounds like a good counter-example!

Comment: how about the exponential distribution?  your chance of exceeding the average $\lambda$ is only 37%, however in normal distribution it is 50%, so if a normal distribution is centred with an exponential distribution with the same mean, the normal is likely to to be higher - although I guess you'd have to truncate the left tail of the normal, so it's a bit messy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that you can simplify the problem by taking $Y=0$ without loss of generality (by comparing $X-Y$ and $0$). Then, what is happening here is that you ask whether the mean equals the median. This is not true in general. For example take $Z$ as the standard exponential distribution and take $X=Z-1$. Then
$$ P(X<0) = P(Z<1) = 1 - e^{-1} \neq \frac{1}{2} $$